# Embed Image to aspx page from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I'm programmatically (server-side) creating an `Image` object after my user chooses some value from a combonox.

I want to embed this image back into the aspx page at runtime, without saving it to disk or database.

So how can I do this? I tried to use memory stream, and send the image with response object, but than I only saw the image - it had overwritten the entire page.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
<img src="yourimagegeneratingpage.aspx?query=value" />
```

When this image will be loaded it will generate a request to your page (yourimagegeneratingpage.aspx) and that page would respond with the image which will be shown by this `img` control.

Answer (score 0):

Create the [Handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) and [request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) it via:

```
<img src="Image.ashx?ID=myImageId" alt="text here"/>

<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image.ashx?ID=myImageId" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could base64 encode the data and write it to the image data.

Like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

For this you will have to render the img tag yourself.

This way you don't have to write your image to a file on the server. It is sent from memory directly to the client browser.

Refer: [Data URI schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

*Note this does not work with IE6.*